# How to convert wordpress page to regular html page?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am trying to make a one page landing page. I want the website to be html based and not wordpress based to make managing it easier. There is a wordpress theme that I really like. Can I do this: 1) install the theme in wordpress 2) view page source 3) copy all code 4) open notepad++ and paste all code 5) save as .html 6) upload html page to the same domain

would this result in a functional website? do you foresee any problems?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? I know of a couple issues you may run into, but it's way too broad for Stack Overflow. I would just do it and then come back here with specific issues.

Answer (score 1):

I found Your post cause same as You I'm total newb to web page building and developing. In the past I've used wordpress theme's to "build and put online" few simple website's - but decided to learn more to be able to create something by myself and have better control of it.

Same as You I thought about using bits of wordpress theme I really like and convert it to html5 - but unfortunately it's not as easy as you described it above.

The way I understand it (someone correct me if I'm wrong please) the main difference is wordpress themes are "dynamic" and html is static kind of web site , and wordpress themes involve different technology (php not html etc) so simply changing changing *.php to *.html will not work:)

there are few ways of doing it though, please find some resources below:

[Using HTTrack to convert WordPress to a static website](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-convert-a-wordpress-site-to-a-static-html-website/)

[Tools to Migrate from WordPress to HTML](https://blog.resellerclub.com/how-to-convert-wordpress-site-to-html/)

hope it helps!